# Three level hierarchical data - How best to structure hop navigation at any level when wizard is stepping at the second last level

Tags: navigation, wizard

**Here is the structure of my data:**
[image: Hierarchical data representation]

**Here is how the first step of the wizard would look like.**
[image: First step of the wizard]

**Here is how they can skip to any further step in the wizard by either selecting a different group or sub group:**
[image]

Now my problem is how do I show that drop list to select when the user is on a step other than the first one. (I don't want these titles [Group and Subgroup] to be as simple dropdowns controls). When the user is on the first group, I can show the list in order. But on the second group, it boils down to something like this, which I think has to have a better way of displaying.
[image]

Comment: Any suggestions ideas thoughts on improving how to show the parent child relationship between level 1 and level 2 (instead of the arrow that I have). Constraint: I need to represent them in a single line dye to space constraint on the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there an issue with just showing a highlighted "Group 2" in the drop down so user know that's the current group they are in.

What I'm trying to say is you don't need to hide "Group 2" in drop list just because your user has selected "Group 2".  See Google Play example below.  Even though user has selected Education, the drop list still contains Education (highlighted):

[image]

Comment: Good suggestion. This example also gives me an idea on how to implement the drop list! Thanks